# How to post parameters array with retrofit?

Tags: android, post, parameters, retrofit

I want to post parameter array.

My parameters look like this :

```
Request
{
                "ProcName" :"BR_SP_BRN_GET_STORE_ACTIVE_SHIPMENTS",
                "Parameters": [
    {
      "Name": "StoreCode",
      "Value": "B201"
    }
  ]
}
```

**And my api interface class like this :**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("GetDispatchList")
Call<TransferCenterStoreResponse> TRANSFER_CENTER_STORE_RESPONSE_CALL(
        @Header("Authorization") String authHeader,
        @Field("ProcName") String procName,
        @Field("Parameters") List<TransferCenterStoreParameters> objects) ;
```

How can i do this with retrofit? Any advice or sample code ?